# Cannot compile example

Tags: scala

I have this class:

```
 class Rational(n:Int, d:Int) {
  require(d!=0)

  private val g = gcd(n.abs, d.abs)

  val numer = n/g
  val denom = d/g

  def this(n: Int) = this(n, 1);

  def add(that:Rational): Rational = new Rational(numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom, denom * that.denom)

  override def toString = numer+"/"+denom;

  private def gcd(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if(b==0) a else gcd(b, a % b)
}
```

And this test class:

```
import Rational

object Test extends App {
  val x = new Rational(1/2)
  println("hello");
}
```

I'm trying to compile them using

```
scalac Test.scala Rational.scala
```

but I get the following error:

```
Test.scala:3: error: '.' expected but ';' found.
object Test extends App {
^
one error found
```

Can someone guide me to why its not compiling. This is a basic error

Comment: remove `import Rational`

Answer (score 2):

`import Rational` is not valid syntax (because it's a class)

As you are in the default package, you don't need an import anyway

Answer (score 1):

Remove `import Rational`.

`Rational` is neither a package nor an Scala object

Why do you have this when you do not have a package declared or Rational declared as object.